# Non mapped properties - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, redux, sequelize-cli

The supports are:  React, Redux and Sequelize.
Basically I want to be able to mark an object as being `dirty` when the Redux store gets updated.

```
function updateCar(carToUpdate, car) {
    switch(car[1]) {
        case "models":
            carToUpdate.models = car[3];
            carToUpdate.setDirty();
            break;
    }    
};
```

Then when someone clicks a save button, I want to only update those models that have their dirty flag set to true

```
var state = request.body;

state.forEach(function (car) {
    if (car && car.isDirty) {
        updateCar(car);
    }
}
```

Now I have following model for the car:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Cars = sequelize.define('Cars',
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      models: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      //Next is NOT working, this does not make it non-mapped
      isDirty: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        scope: false
      },
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          // associations can be defined here
        }
      },
      instanceMethods: {
        setDirty: function() {
          this.isDirty = true;
        }
      }
    });
  return Cars;
};
```

Anyone who has experience with non-mapped fields or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it eventually.

The model of the car should contain a `VIRTUAL` property:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Cars = sequelize.define('Cars',
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      models: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      isDirty: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
      },
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          // associations can be defined here
        }
      }
    });
  return Cars;
};
```

Next the flag should be set when updating the values:

```
function updateCar(carToUpdate, car) {
    switch(car[1]) {
        case "models":
            carToUpdate.models = car[3];
            carToUpdate.isDirty = true;
            break;
    }    
};
```

Then the save method can check the `isDirty` flag
    var state = request.body;

```
state.forEach(function (car) {
    if (car && car.isDirty) {
        console.log(car.name +": "+ car.isDirty);
        updateCar(car);
    }
}, this);
```

Last but not least, we reset the `isDirty` flag to false so we do not update the same models over and over.

```
var save = function () {
    var state = carStore.getState();
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/Cars/update",
        data: JSON.stringify(state),
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).then(function() {
        carStore.dispatch({
            type: 'resetDirty',
            data: null
        });
    });
};
```

And the dispatch method for resetting the flag:

```
function updateReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'load':
            return action.data;
        case 'update':
            return updateCars(action.carChanges, state);
        case 'resetDirty':
            return resetDirtyFlags(state);
        default:
            return action.data;
    }

}

function resetDirtyFlags(state) {
    var newState = $.extend(true, [], state);
    if(state) {
        newState.forEach(function(car) {
            car.isDirty = false;
        }, this);
        return newState;
    }
    return newState;
}
```